# Having my user folders symlinked to my secondary 2tb hard drive is causing my computer to lock up

Tags: 18.04

Having my user folders (Downloads, Pictures, Videos, Documents) to my secondarey 2tb hard drive is causing my computer to lock up and the cpu usage spikes to 100% also a tracker-extraction procsess going on the uses a lot of CPU.

The system is semi usable after this happens but some apps frezze and won't open for example Nautilus. Trying to run it from the command line gives me and error about timeout reached

Comment: What makes you think the symlinks are at fault? I do something very similar, symlinking **Downloads, Music, Pictures, Videos** to an 2T HDD, and have never experienced this. Can you be more specific as to what is happening when the CPU spikes occur?

Comment: The symlinks are the only thing I can think of that I did to my computer recently that could of caused this also this happens only  when I try to access a file through it. Certain apps start show not resp errors including Stacer, Nautilus, and gnome system monitor. If I kill any of those apps and try to relaunch them they don't open. Trying to open them through the terminal times out. I agree it very strange and unlikely for the symlinks to be the cause. I'm thinking that maybe the tracker-extraction process is maybe for some reason not liking that I'm doing a symlinks or something

Comment: You may want to run some diagnostics on the 2TB drive. Also, try to access one of the symlinked folders via its true location; this will at least narrow things down.

Comment: well thats weird I turned off my system for a while and turned it back on and its no longer hanging  when I access my symlinks. I also did a check on my drive and it came back fine

Comment: Good to hear, @andres-ortiz.

Comment: okay I maybe figured it out Spotify is giving me an error that its cant access the symlink because of a permissions error this might be related. spotify is a snap and I going to confirmed other snaps have this issue

Comment: Where did you `mount` your *secondary-drive* as snaps have greater restrictions on where on your file-system they can go (the symlink being in your $HOME matters less than where it points to)

Comment: /mnt/SSHD and yup just confirmed it the issue is problem some snap is trying to acsses the symlink and failes just tried other snaps and get the same error do snaps not have accses to drives mounted in /mnt ?

Comment: Snaps are designed to be confined by default. They can only access what you explicitly tell the system to permit them to access. They may NOT traverse your filesystem on fishing expeditions. Simply tell snapd to give the snap access to the dir in /mnt that you want.