# Kernel panic after 30 min or so in 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, kernel

After using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on this PC for about half an hour, it suddenly locks up and stops responding. I try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> and login, but any command entered hangs, eventually showing an error **task blocked for more than 120 seconds**.

Just ran a memory test and everything came back fine but IDK I'm still convinced it might be a hardware issue just because of all the other problems I have. Such as the computer sometimes boot to a black screen no bios logo or anything or the several other questions I have posted here in ask ubuntu such as an issue where the computer would randomly fail to load my profile getting stuck in a black screen [askubuntu gnome-black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144625/black-screen-after-login-18-04) or me having issues with symlinking my user folders like Documents to my SSHD and then getting high CPU usage and freezes [ask ubuntu issue with symlinks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176449/having-my-user-folders-symlinked-to-my-secondary-2tb-hard-drive-is-causing-my-co) I don't know how helpful the output I posted of my system specs would be as it got cut off but I do know my specs from memory as I built this computer.

**CPU:** AMD Ryzen 2700x

**Motherboard:** Gigabyte Arous GAMING x470

**Bios V.:** F41

**RAM:** XPG Z1 DDR4 3000MHz (PC4 24000) 16GB (2x8GB) Gaming Memory Modules, 
Silver (AX4U300038G16-DSZ1)

**Video Card:** Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1080 Windforce OC GV-N1080WF3OC-8GD 
Graphics Cards)

**Power Supply:**   Corsair TXM Gold 550 W 80+ Gold Certified Semi-modular ATX

**DRIVES:** M.2  drives 1 Samsung EVO 970(Linux) && 1 Samsung EVO 960 (Windows)
1 SEAGATE 2TB SSHD(games and user files)
1TB SEAGATE Drive HDD (Backups)

How do I troubleshoot this?

Output of cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth" && lshw | grep product | head -n1 && lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)  && lshw | grep -v "loop"

```
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:29 ioport:f000(size=4096) memory:f7200000-f75fffff
       *-usb
            description: USB controller
            product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            version: 01
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
            resources: irq:32 memory:f75a0000-f75a7fff
       *-storage
            description: SATA controller
            product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
            version: 01
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
            resources: irq:67 memory:f7580000-f759ffff memory:f7500000-f757ffff
       *-pci
            description: PCI bridge
            product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            physical id: 0.2
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.2
            version: 01
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=pcieport
            resources: irq:34 ioport:f000(size=4096) memory:f7200000-f74fffff
          *-pci:0
               description: PCI bridge
               product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
               vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
               physical id: 0
               bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
               version: 01
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:35
          *-pci:1
               description: PCI bridge
               product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
               vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
               physical id: 1
               bus info: pci@0000:03:01.0
               version: 01
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:36
          *-pci:2
               description: PCI bridge
               product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
               vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
               physical id: 2
               bus info: pci@0000:03:02.0
               version: 01
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:37
          *-pci:3
               description: PCI bridge
               product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
               vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
               physical id: 3
               bus info: pci@0000:03:03.0
               version: 01
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:39 ioport:f000(size=4096) memory:f7400000-f74fffff
             *-network
                  description: Ethernet interface
                  product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
                  vendor: Intel Corporation
                  physical id: 0
                  bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
                  logical name: enp7s0
                  version: 03
                  serial: e0:d5:5e:a6:73:6a
                  size: 1Gbit/s
                  capacity: 1Gbit/s
                  width: 32 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                  configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 6-1 ip=192.168.1.213 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
                  resources: irq:38 memory:f7400000-f741ffff ioport:f000(size=32) memory:f7420000-f7423fff
          *-pci:4
               description: PCI bridge
               product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
               vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
               physical id: 4
               bus info: pci@0000:03:04.0
               version: 01
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:40 memory:f7300000-f73fffff
             *-storage
                  description: Non-Volatile memory controller
                  product: NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
                  vendor: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
                  physical id: 0
                  bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
                  version: 00
                  width: 64 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: storage nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                  configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
                  resources: irq:110 memory:f7300000-f7303fff
          *-pci:5
               description: PCI bridge
               product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
               vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
               physical id: 9
               bus info: pci@0000:03:09.0
               version: 01
               width: 32 bits
               clock: 33MHz
               capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
               configuration: driver=pcieport
               resources: irq:41 memory:f7200000-f72fffff
             *-usb
                  description: USB controller
                  product: ASM1143 USB 3.1 Host Controller
                  vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
                  physical id: 0
                  bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
                  version: 00
                  width: 64 bits
                  clock: 33MHz
                  capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
                  configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                  resources: irq:25 memory:f7200000-f7207fff
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 3.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:03.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:30 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f6000000-f70fffff ioport:e0000000(size=301989888)
       *-display
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080]
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
            version: a1
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
            resources: irq:125 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
       *-multimedia
            description: Audio device
            product: GP104 High Definition Audio Controller
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.1
            version: a1
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
            resources: irq:121 memory:f7080000-f7083fff
    *-pci:3
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 7.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:07.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:31 memory:f7600000-f78fffff
       *-generic:0 UNCLAIMED
            description: Non-Essential Instrumentation
            product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
            version: 00
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
       *-generic:1
            description: Encryption controller
            product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            physical id: 0.2
            bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.2
            version: 00
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=ccp latency=0
            resources: irq:70 memory:f7700000-f77fffff memory:f7800000-f7801fff
       *-usb
            description: USB controller
            product: USB 3.0 Host controller
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            physical id: 0.3
            bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.3
            version: 00
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
            resources: irq:58 memory:f7600000-f76fffff
    *-pci:4
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 8.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:08.1
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:33 memory:f7900000-f79fffff
       *-generic UNCLAIMED
            description: Non-Essential Instrumentation
            product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
            version: 00
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: cap_list
            configuration: latency=0
       *-storage
            description: SATA controller
            product: FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            physical id: 0.2
            bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.2
            version: 51
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
            resources: irq:77 memory:f7908000-f7908fff
       *-multimedia
            description: Audio device
            product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
            vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
            physical id: 0.3
            bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.3
            version: 00
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
            resources: irq:123 memory:f7900000-f7907fff
    *-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: FCH SMBus Controller
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 59
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         configuration: latency=0
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: FCH LPC Bridge
         vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
         physical id: 14.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
         version: 51
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master
         configuration: latency=0
 *-pci:1
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 101
      bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:2
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 102
      bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
 *-pci:3
      description: Host bridge
      product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
      vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
      physical id: 103
      bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
      version: 00
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 107
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:8
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 108
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:9
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 109
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:10
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 10a
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:11
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 10b
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:12
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 10c
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:13
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 10d
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.6
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:14
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 10e
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.7
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-scsi
          physical id: 2
          bus info: usb@5:3
          logical name: scsi9
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVDRAM GP65NB60
             vendor: HL-DT-ST
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@9:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: PF00
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: status=nodisc
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: anbox0
       serial: 66:96:5d:fc:11:e0
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.250.1 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:76:04:ae
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: 52:54:00:76:04:ae
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

Comment: "just because of all the other problems I have" What other problems? Please click [edit] and tell us. Also, please run `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth" && lshw | grep product | head -n1 && lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)  && lshw | grep -v "loop"` then click [edit] to add the facts to your question. Please do not click Add Comment, please use [edit] instead. Editing tips are at https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code .  PS: Memory tests are not infallible; if they find something good, but often they don't; we have other ways to help.

Answer (score 0):

okay I was able to fix this issue apparently the bios were not installed correctly or maybe the version I was using had Linux problems (I have heard that amd bios are having a lot of issues with Linux). point is I updated to F42A and no more kernal panics